# Time-lapse Windows desktop wallpaper

Tags: windows, photography, wallpaper

Years ago -- probably last century, haha -- I used a little app for Windows that would synchronize with the system clock and set the desktop wallpaper to the appropriate image from a set of time lapse photographs of a scene (I remember it came with a beautiful image of San Francisco Bay). I'm about 99% sure it was called "Sundial".

Does anyone know if a similar program exists today? Alternatively, is there a way to download a Windows theme that consists of time lapse images, and set the wallpaper change interval to achieve the same effect?

Comment: It might be significant to mention which version of Windows you would like this to run on.

Answer (score 1):

I currently use a program called [Johns Background Switcher](http://downloads.johnsadventures.com/SwitcherSetup410.exe) that you could configure to do this. It doesn't come with a time lapse feature per-say but you can easily setup a folder full of images and then set it to change pictures how ever often you want (anywhere from every 10 seconds to every 7 days). I thought it had an option to not shuffle the pictures, because it has a lot more options than the standard Windows 7 slideshow (if that's what version you're on), but I just looked and it doesn't. This wouldn't be hard to integrate into the app though and I'm sure if sent the developer a request for it he would add it.

The other option I might look into would be a program called [Stardock Descapes](http://www.stardock.com/products/deskscapes/downloads.asp). Descapes won't change a picture based on the time of day but it can add some really cool motion to your desktop and there are a **ton** of 'dreams' in their archives that you can download. You should easily be able to find a few in there you like, or even create your own. Their is a 'free trial' button on their websit but for some reason it takes you to a page which asks you to buy it, so I don't know that the issue is there. It's worth the $10 lifetime license though. I'm planning to get one eventually. Hope this helps and you can make one of these options work for you!